# PyDev - Eclipse console lines missing from the end

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

On many occasions, I have come across a problem with the Eclipse console not showing the complete debug output of my python scripts. The last lines of the output are sometimes missing, as if the Console "shuts down" before the complete output of the script was processed.

I am not sure about the interactions between PyDev, the debugger and the Eclipse Console window, so it is hard to pinpoint the problem - especially because it behaves differently each times I start a new debug session.

Until now, my scripts were this happens were too large to post here completely, but I was recently playing around with the random module and saw it happen again:

```python
import random
rand = random.Random(9572)

for i in range(10):
    print i, rand.randrange(256)
```

[image: PyDev console with missing last lines]

Of course, the complete output (which I also get *sometimes*) should be

```
pydev debugger: starting
0 157
1 18
2 136
3 171
4 136
5 62
6 26
7 13
8 37
9 1
```

Am I the only one with that problem?

If not, any pointers on how to solve it?

Note that I am using Eclipse Juno SR1 (Build id: M20120914-1800) with PyDev 2.7.1.2012100913 under Windows 7.

Thanks in advance!

---

Because of abarnert's comment below, I just tried with the 2.7.0.2012100419 PyDev version. Same problem.

Comment: What platform, version, Eclipse/PyDev version, and anything else that might be relevant? (And, if the versions are old, and you think it might be a bug… have you tried a newer version?)

Comment: Actually, 2.7.1.2012100913 looks like a prerelease version. http://pydev.org says the latest is 2.7.0. Maybe try 2.7.0 (or a newer prerelease)?

Comment: @abarnert 2.7.1.2012100913 appears to be the latest PyDev version according to the update site http://pydev.org/updates/. The next older version seems to be 2.7.0.2012100419... why are you saying "looks like a prerelease"?

Comment: Because the top status bar at http://pydev.org says "Latest Version: 2.7.0". It's possible they forgot to update the page, or I just don't understand their update policy, or… Anyway, whatever the reason, it looks like that was probably a red herring; if they're pushing 2.7.1 in their updater, presumably that's what you're supposed to use. Apologies for the side-track.

Comment: I have the correct output, I am using Eclipse Juno 20120614-1722 and pydev 2.7.1.2012100913, on both the debug and the run.

Comment: @Sam, could you check with the updated sample code, seems to be better to reproduce the problem. Are you running an older version of Eclipse? Mine says Build id: M20120914-1800. Also, have you tried to debug it multiple times? I sometimes get the correct output, too.

Comment: I have experienced a similar error where if you run a python script in the IDE, it does not fully output the last line of the expected output. It seems like the software is somehow "shutting down early" as you mentioned. This does not occur when running the exact same scripts on the command line. I am using LiClipse 2.5.4.201603221237 with the PyDev that came installed with it.